# Test Spring MVC response pattern (Ignore a json field in the items in the response )

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am testing a spring MVC application.
I need to be sure that the response to the browser has a certain pattern, my application sends back some json, and for each Json item there is a field called DT_RowId that I do not want to compare, because DT_RowId contains a random number. Therefore, I would like to compare all the Json body, except DT_RowId and its content. 
By the way a typical occurence of DT_RowId is "DT_RowId":"8407709537703772". And a typical json response is:

```
{"id":-1,"fieldErrors":[],"aaData":[{"id":8002,"firstname":"Bob","lastname":"Jones","email":"bob.jones@gmail.com","DT_RowId":"8407709537703772"},{"id":8002,"firstname:"Dan","lastname":"Jones","email":"dan.jones@gmail.com","DT_RowId":"8404309537701754"}]}
```

Below, my test:

```
@Test
public void testGetUsersJson() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/users")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

        .andDo(print())

        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
        // How can I modify the line below??
        .andExpect(content().bytes(IOUtils.toByteArray(ctx.getResource("classpath:responses/users.getUsersJson.mywebapp.response.json").getInputStream())))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(redirectedUrl(null))
        .andExpect(forwardedUrl(null));
}
```

How can I modify the code above? I would like to compare all the Json response except the field"DT_RowId". Any clever ideas?

Comment: Do you need the `DT_RowId` field?  If not, why not omit it from your JSON response?

Comment: yes, I need DT_RowId field, otherwise the question would not have any sense

Comment: It was just a question.  If you are not using the DT_RowId in the client at all, then omitting it would make comparing easier.  Sometimes people don't see the obvious because they are looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to add an extra dependency to your project, this can be achieved using the [JsonUnit Spring MVC integration](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit#spring-mvc-assertions) and formatting your JSON as below

```
{
    "id": -1,
    "fieldErrors": [],
    "aaData": [
        {
            "id": 8002,
            "firstname": "Bob",
            "lastname": "Jones",
            "email": "bob.jones@gmail.com",
            "DT_RowId": "${json-unit.any-number}"
        },
        {
            "id": 8002,
            "firstname": "Dan",
            "lastname": "Jones",
            "email": "dan.jones@gmail.com",
            "DT_RowId": "${json-unit.any-number}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use andExpect(content().matches(regex here)), and write a regex to match your users.getUsersJson.mywebapp.response.json content excluding your DT_RowId.

Comment: Using a regex to validate JSON is very cumbersome and not JSON-compliant. I would recommend using https://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/

Comment: [json-unit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit) is also good.